# Bash will not reload aliases

Tags: raspbian

I was making a small script to add some aliases that I use:

```
if [ ! -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
        echo "alias update='$SCRIPT_DIR/update.sh'" > ~/.bash_aliases
        echo "alias ll='ls -lah --color=auto'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
        source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

My intent is to reload `.bashrc` after adding those alias to `.bash_aliases`.
After executing the script my `.bash_aliases` is created but my aliases do not work.

When I check for all alias, those I created aren't loaded.
So, It seems to me that `source ~/.bashrc` is not working. Only if I input `source ~/.bashrc` outside the script that it loads the new `.bash_aliases`.

Can someone help out?
Thanks

Comment: your script is running in a new shell ... try executing the script using `source your_script_name_goes_here`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=run+source+.bashrc+from+a+shell+script&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS497US497&oq=run+source+.bashrc+from+a+shell+script&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.15130j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Steve, thank you for your reference. I now understand why it does not work right away. Using `source <script_name>` to start my script, as suggested by Joramanda, worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I could not update my bash to be interactive inside a script.

`set-i` does not seems to work, and neither changing `$-`.

Only by using `source ~/.bashrc` it did work for me.

```
if [ ! -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
        echo -e "\nUser aliases not found. Creating...\n"
        echo "alias update='source $SCRIPT_DIR/$SCRIPT_NAME'" > ~/.bash_aliases
        echo "alias ll='ls -lah --color=auto'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
        source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

By the way, I changed any `exit` I had in my script to `return` to avoid exiting my current shell.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.